# Dealing with missing information while converting a list into data frame or data table

Tags: r, data.table

Related to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31272379/converting-a-list-of-named-elements-into-a-data-frame-or-data-table) is there any way to convert a list of named elements where some names are duplicated into a data table where NA values actually show up in the data table in the order that they appear in the list?

For Example: The list

```
testlist <- list("Blue", "405", "Truck", "400", "Car", "White", "500", "Truck")
testnames <- c("Color", "HP", "Type", "HP", "Type", "Color", "HP", "Type")
names(testlist) <- testnames

$Color
[1] "Blue"

$HP
[1] "405"

$Type
[1] "Truck"

$HP
[1] "400"

$Type
[1] "Car"

$Color
[1] "White"

$HP
[1] "500"

$Type
[1] "Truck"
```

Can be changed into a data table using:

```
dcast(setDT(melt(testlist))[, N:=1:.N, L1], N~L1, value.var='value')
```

But output is this:

```
  N Color  HP  Type
1 1  Blue 405 Truck
2 2 White 400   Car
3 3  <NA> 500 Truck
```

When I want:

```
  N Color  HP  Type
1 1  Blue 405 Truck
2 2  <NA> 400   Car
3 3 White 500 Truck
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for how to tackle this problem? I appreciate the help.

Comment: this is quite prickly... how in the world did you end up with `testlist` in the first place?

Comment: @MichaelChirico I agree with you, I am building a web scraping tool and the only way I have figured out how to get the data that I want is in a format of 2 character vectors (the attributes and the titles of those attributes). I put them in a list because I figured that the best way to ultimately end up with what I wanted was to start from a list where each attribute is tied to it's respective name. There is probably a much better way to do the whole thing but as I am fairly new to web scraping, this is the best I could come up with.

Comment: Why doesn't the scraper return `NA`s?

Comment: Another possibility might be to build a counter into your scraper so that your names vector would be `c("Color 1","HP 1","Type 1","HP 2","Type 2","Color 3","HP 3","Type 3")`--would make this whole exercise substantially easier

Comment: That's a good suggestion, I'll see what I can work into what I have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach is to preallocate a table with the correct number of rows and the correct number, names, and types of columns, and then fill it in by index-assigning the cells covered by the original list.

```
cns <- c('Color','HP','Type');
lcis <- match(names(testlist),cns);
lris <- c(1L,cumsum(diff(lcis)<=0L)+1L);
df <- as.data.frame(testlist[match(1:length(cns),lcis)],stringsAsFactors=F)[0,];
df[max(lris),] <- NA;
df;
##   Color   HP Type
## 1  <NA> <NA> <NA>
## 2  <NA> <NA> <NA>
## 3  <NA> <NA> <NA>
for (ci in 1:length(cns)) { m <- lcis==ci; df[lris[m],ci] <- do.call(c,testlist[m]); };
df;
##   Color  HP  Type
## 1  Blue 405 Truck
## 2  <NA> 400   Car
## 3 White 500 Truck
```

In my solution I was careful to handle each column separately, which provides the potential benefit that if different columns in the output table (corresponding to different subsets of components in the input list) have different data types, then those data types will be preserved in the final table. This is why I opted for a `for` loop for the index-assignment. This is of course not necessary for your exact input list, which has only character types, but I thought it was a worthy goal anyway.

## Explanation of intermediate variables

- `cns` The column names in the output table.
- `lcis` The column indexes each input list component will have in the output table. This is computed by simply matching the names of the input list components against `cns`.
- `lris` The row indexes each input list component will have in the output table. The computation of this variable is somewhat interesting and central to the solution. Since column representation in the input list is incomplete (IOW there can be "missing columns" in the input list), but you consider the input list components to be ordered with respect to their row-wise occurrence in the output table, we can't use regular indexing (such as taking every three components as a row), and we also can't use any single column name as a marker of each row, because any column can be missing in any row. From my thinking, the only correct approach is to identify when a lower-index (or equal-index, actually) column occurs immediately after a higher-index (or equal-index) column in the input list, and take those as row breaks. Hence, we can take `diff(lcis)<=0L` to get a logical vector representing row breaks, take the `cumsum()` and add 1 to get the row indexes, and we also must manually prepend 1 to complete the vector.
- `ci` The column index in the output table. Used during the `for` loop to iterate over each output column.
- `m` Computed for each `ci` within the `for` loop. A logical vector representing which of the input list components belong to the current column `ci`. Used to index both `lris` (to pull out the row indexes to assign), and the input list itself (to pull out the actual values to assign).

---

## Actual Data

I grabbed your real data from dropbox and stored it as `testlist`. Below are the results of my investigations.

First, I examined the unique component names in the order they occur, taking them as `cns`:

```
## first reasonable assumption about cns
cns <- unique(names(testlist));
cns;
##  [1] "Status"              "Make"                "Model"
##  [4] "Kilometres"          "Stock Number"        "Engine"
##  [7] "Number of Hours"     "Front axle"          "Rear axle"
## [10] "Suspension"          "Wheelbase"           "Transmission"
## [13] "Price"               "Style/Trim"          "Brakes"
## [16] "Mfg Exterior Colour" "Tires"               "Engine (HP)"
## [19] "Exterior Colour"
```

From which we can compute a new tentative `lcis`:

```
## examine lcis for ordering
lcis <- match(names(testlist),cns);
lcis;
##   [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
##  [26] 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
##  [51] 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
##  [76] 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
## [101] 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
## [126]  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
## [151]  8  9 10 11 12 13  1  2  3  4 14 13  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
## [176]  1  2  3  4  5 15 16  6  8  9 10 17 11 18 12 19 13  1  2  3  4  5 15 16  6
## [201]  8  9 10 17 11 18 12 19 13
```

Looking carefully at the above vector, we can see that it begins with many regular repetitions of `1:13`. In fact, only towards the end of the vector does it become irregular, where we see 14 followed by 13, and 16 followed by 6, 10-11-12 interleaved with 17-18-19, etc.

But one important observation we can make here is that the vector seems to consist of groups delineated by 1 and 13. In other words, for all extents that seem to have some regularity (even if there is also some irregularity), they seem to begin with 1 and end with 13. This observation agrees with your comment regarding disorder in the middle of vehicle data. Let's call this the 1/13 assumption.

We can get a clearer view of the groups by splitting on this 1/13 boundary:

```
## recognizing 1/13 consistency, split on it to see how each (possible) row looks under this assumption
split(lcis,cumsum(lcis==1L));
## $`1`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`2`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`3`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`4`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`5`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`6`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`7`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`8`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`9`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`10`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`11`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`12`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`13`
## [1]  1  2  3  4 14 13
##
## $`14`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
##
## $`15`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5 15 16  6  8  9 10 17 11 18 12 19 13
##
## $`16`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5 15 16  6  8  9 10 17 11 18 12 19 13
```

Now, if you look *very* carefully at the above groups, you can figure out that it is possible to reorder `cns` in such a way that all groups will be ordered ascending. They will not be contiguous, but contiguity is not required for the solution I devised for the original problem; all that is necessary is ascending order.

For instance, we need to order column 14 before 13, and we need to order columns 15 and 16 before 6, 8, 9, etc.:

```
## recognizing the possibility of reordering to achieve perfect within-row ascending order, reorder cns to cns2
cns2 <- cns[c(1,2,3,4,14,5,15,16,6,7,8,9,10,17,11,18,12,19,13)];
cns2;
##  [1] "Status"              "Make"                "Model"
##  [4] "Kilometres"          "Style/Trim"          "Stock Number"
##  [7] "Brakes"              "Mfg Exterior Colour" "Engine"
## [10] "Number of Hours"     "Front axle"          "Rear axle"
## [13] "Suspension"          "Tires"               "Wheelbase"
## [16] "Engine (HP)"         "Transmission"        "Exterior Colour"
## [19] "Price"
```

Now we can recalculate `lcis`, which I will now call `lcis2`, and demonstrate the new group orders:

```
## calculate lcis2 from cns2, and prove that we've successfully ordered each individual row under the 1/13 (now 1/19) break assumption
lcis2 <- match(names(testlist),cns2);
split(lcis2,cumsum(lcis2==1L));
## $`1`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`2`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`3`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`4`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`5`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`6`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`7`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`8`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`9`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`10`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`11`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`12`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`13`
## [1]  1  2  3  4  5 19
##
## $`14`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  9 10 11 12 13 15 17 19
##
## $`15`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
##
## $`16`
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
```

And finally, we can run the entire solution, being careful to use the 2-suffixed variable names now:

```
## now we can apply the preallocate/fill-in solution using cns2 and lcis2
## will use lris2 and df2 just to be consistent
lris2 <- c(1L,cumsum(diff(lcis2)<=0L)+1L);
df2 <- as.data.frame(testlist[match(1:length(cns2),lcis2)],stringsAsFactors=F)[0,];
df2[max(lris2),] <- NA;
df2;
##    Status Make Model Kilometres Style.Trim Stock.Number Brakes Mfg.Exterior.Colour Engine Number.of.Hours Front.axle Rear.axle Suspension Tires Wheelbase Engine..HP. Transmission Exterior.Colour Price
## 1    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 2    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 3    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 4    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 5    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 6    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 7    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 8    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 9    <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 10   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 11   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 12   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 13   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 14   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 15   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
## 16   <NA> <NA>  <NA>       <NA>       <NA>         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>   <NA>            <NA>       <NA>      <NA>       <NA>  <NA>      <NA>        <NA>         <NA>            <NA>  <NA>
for (ci in 1:length(cns2)) { m <- lcis2==ci; df2[lris2[m],ci] <- do.call(c,testlist[m]); };
df2;
##    Status          Make                                          Model Kilometres    Style.Trim Stock.Number Brakes Mfg.Exterior.Colour                  Engine Number.of.Hours                     Front.axle                      Rear.axle                     Suspension    Tires Wheelbase Engine..HP.                   Transmission Exterior.Colour    Price
## 1     New     Peterbilt                 367 Tri-Drive c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,360 km          <NA>        12949   <NA>                <NA> Cummins ISX15  (550 hp)              44  Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000lb) Dana T69-170    (wide track) t Peterbilt Air-Trak  (66,000lb)     <NA>     267''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $217,770
## 2     New      Kenworth                               T800 T/A Tractor  82,230 km          <NA>        10720   <NA>                <NA>   Cummins ISX15 (550hp)           2,712 Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000 lb) Dana D46-170HPW (46,000 lb) ta Neway ADZ252    (52,000lb) Air     <NA>     244''        <NA> Fuller 18 spd main AT1202 2 sp            <NA> $199,500
## 3     New      Kenworth            T800 Tandem Tractor w/ 38'' Sleeper  98,521 km          <NA>        10722   <NA>                <NA>   Cummins ISX15 (550hp)           2,790 Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000 lb) Dana D46-170HPW (46,000 lb) ta Neway ADZ252    (52,000lb) Air     <NA>     244''        <NA> Fuller 18 spd main AT1202 2 sp            <NA> $199,500
## 4    Used      Kenworth           W900 Tri-Drive Sleeper Truck Tractor 170,422 km          <NA>        13227   <NA>                <NA> Cummins ISX15  (600 hp)           4,925 Meritor FL941      (20,000 lb)  Meritor RZ-166    (69,000 lb)  Kenworth AG690 (69,000lb) Air     <NA>     259''        <NA> 18 speed main &     4 speed au            <NA> $197,750
## 5     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,367 km          <NA>        12180   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              38 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $193,300
## 6     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,421 km          <NA>        12179   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              46 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $193,300
## 7     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   2,157 km          <NA>        12181   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              64 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $189,880
## 8     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,444 km          <NA>        12954   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              45 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $189,880
## 9     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,427 km          <NA>        12955   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              43 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $189,880
## 10    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,982 km          <NA>        12182   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              78 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $189,880
## 11    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper  23,293 km          <NA>        12953   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)             394 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $189,880
## 12    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper  27,215 km          <NA>        12509   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)             458 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $186,600
## 13   Used         Volvo                                 VNL64T 780-730  72,000 km VNL64T780-730         <NA>   <NA>                <NA>                    <NA>            <NA>                           <NA>                           <NA>                           <NA>     <NA>      <NA>        <NA>                           <NA>            <NA> $185,000
## 14    New     Peterbilt 367 T/A Wet Kit Tractor c/w       58'' Sleeper  60,657 km          <NA>        10838   <NA>                <NA>  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)           1,822 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170HP (46,000lb) tand Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     <NA>     244''        <NA>  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)            <NA> $171,800
## 15   Used International                                   ProStar +122  36,236 km          <NA>       463555    Air               White             Cummins ISX            <NA>         Arvin Meritor 13200 lb         Arvin Meritor 40000 lb                     Int'l IROS  11R22.5    228 in         450      Eaton Fuller D/O (18 spd)           White $168,750
## 16   Used International                                   ProStar +122  33,000 km          <NA>       463543    Air               White             Cummins ISX            <NA>         Arvin Meritor 13200 lb         Arvin Meritor 46000 lb                     Int'l IROS 11R/22.5    236 in         475      Eaton Fuller D/O (18 spd)           White $165,900
```

Now, I realized that it might be preferable to move away entirely from the "ascending-order assumption" (let's call it) to the 1/13 assumption, which we can do very simply by changing the `lris` calculation. This will absolve us of the need to reorder `cns` from the order we receive from the `unique()` call.

Below I demonstrate this, reverting back to the unsuffixed variable names, which will be useful, as will be seen in a moment:

```
## change lris calculation to depend directly on 1/13 assumption; don't bother reordering
cns <- unique(names(testlist));
lcis <- match(names(testlist),cns);
lris <- c(1L,cumsum(lcis[-1]==1L)+1L);
df <- as.data.frame(testlist[match(1:length(cns),lcis)],stringsAsFactors=F)[0,];
df[max(lris),] <- NA;
for (ci in 1:length(cns)) { m <- lcis==ci; df[lris[m],ci] <- do.call(c,testlist[m]); };
df;
##    Status          Make                                          Model Kilometres Stock.Number                  Engine Number.of.Hours                     Front.axle                      Rear.axle                     Suspension Wheelbase                   Transmission    Price    Style.Trim Brakes Mfg.Exterior.Colour    Tires Engine..HP. Exterior.Colour
## 1     New     Peterbilt                 367 Tri-Drive c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,360 km        12949 Cummins ISX15  (550 hp)              44  Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000lb) Dana T69-170    (wide track) t Peterbilt Air-Trak  (66,000lb)     267''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $217,770          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 2     New      Kenworth                               T800 T/A Tractor  82,230 km        10720   Cummins ISX15 (550hp)           2,712 Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000 lb) Dana D46-170HPW (46,000 lb) ta Neway ADZ252    (52,000lb) Air     244'' Fuller 18 spd main AT1202 2 sp $199,500          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 3     New      Kenworth            T800 Tandem Tractor w/ 38'' Sleeper  98,521 km        10722   Cummins ISX15 (550hp)           2,790 Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000 lb) Dana D46-170HPW (46,000 lb) ta Neway ADZ252    (52,000lb) Air     244'' Fuller 18 spd main AT1202 2 sp $199,500          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 4    Used      Kenworth           W900 Tri-Drive Sleeper Truck Tractor 170,422 km        13227 Cummins ISX15  (600 hp)           4,925 Meritor FL941      (20,000 lb)  Meritor RZ-166    (69,000 lb)  Kenworth AG690 (69,000lb) Air     259'' 18 speed main &     4 speed au $197,750          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 5     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,367 km        12180  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              38 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $193,300          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 6     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,421 km        12179  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              46 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $193,300          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 7     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   2,157 km        12181  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              64 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $189,880          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 8     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,444 km        12954  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              45 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $189,880          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 9     New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,427 km        12955  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              43 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $189,880          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 10    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper   3,982 km        12182  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)              78 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $189,880          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 11    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper  23,293 km        12953  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)             394 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $189,880          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 12    New     Peterbilt       367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper  27,215 km        12509  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)             458 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $186,600          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 13   Used         Volvo                                 VNL64T 780-730  72,000 km         <NA>                    <NA>            <NA>                           <NA>                           <NA>                           <NA>      <NA>                           <NA> $185,000 VNL64T780-730   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 14    New     Peterbilt 367 T/A Wet Kit Tractor c/w       58'' Sleeper  60,657 km        10838  Cummins ISX15  (550hp)           1,822 Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb Dana D46-170HP (46,000lb) tand Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)     244''  RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed) $171,800          <NA>   <NA>                <NA>     <NA>        <NA>            <NA>
## 15   Used International                                   ProStar +122  36,236 km       463555             Cummins ISX            <NA>         Arvin Meritor 13200 lb         Arvin Meritor 40000 lb                     Int'l IROS    228 in      Eaton Fuller D/O (18 spd) $168,750          <NA>    Air               White  11R22.5         450           White
## 16   Used International                                   ProStar +122  33,000 km       463543             Cummins ISX            <NA>         Arvin Meritor 13200 lb         Arvin Meritor 46000 lb                     Int'l IROS    236 in      Eaton Fuller D/O (18 spd) $165,900          <NA>    Air               White 11R/22.5         475           White
```

As you can see, the column order of `df` is different from `df2`, but we can prove the data is identical with the following:

```
## prove df2 and df are identical, ignoring the column order difference
identical(df,df2[names(df)]);
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is a great solution! However it is contingent of the fact that the there is an ultimate order in the `cns` vector within `testlist`. The data that I am working with is quite unorganized but each vehicle will begin with a `Color` entry and end with a `Type` entry, but the ordering of the data in the middle can change. I am trying to play around with how `lcis` is computed in order to fix this but maybe you have a quick fix. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The second row in your example data has no `Color`. And there are only three columns in the data you've presented, so I'm not sure how each row can begin with `Color`, end with `Type`, and have out-of-order middle columns. Can you paste your actual input data into the question, or perhaps dropbox? Thank you!

Comment: I would be happy to post it to a dropbox, is there a particular file format that you would like it in? I scraped all the data from the internet so I can write it to a file that you can read back into R.

Comment: If you have it in R, then the output of `dput()` would be perfect, since that can be read back into R directly.

Comment: i was aiming for something like this but couldn't get it to work, nicely done!

Comment: @bgoldst [Link to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lz4xv9m1cicv36y/AACRrUHUulaCXsOiBjuhiMA6a?dl=0)

Comment: Why is `Status=NA` for 16th row of `df`?

Comment: @Khashaa Thank you! I'd pasted in an out-of-date piece of output, which I'd generated before my code was 100% correct. The code is correct, however. I've fixed the output now.

Comment: @bgoldst You are a hero. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Best solution I could come up with

```
library(data.table)
listnames <- names(testlist) 
# "Color" "HP"    "Type"  "HP"    "Type"  "Color" "HP"    "Type" 

unames <- unique(listnames)
# "Color" "HP"    "Type"

a <- setNames(1:length(unames), unames)
# Color    HP  Type 
# 1     2     3 

d <- unname(a[listnames])
# [1] 1 2 3 2 3 1 2 3

splitted_list <- split(testlist, cumsum(shift(d, fill=0)>d))
# results in testlist splitted by increasing sequences in d
# (1,2,3), (2,3), (1, 2, 3)
# You can impose a different splitting condition here, for instance, 
# if each entry begins with 1, then cumsum(d==1) is adequate 

# and the last step is pretty much self explanatory
rbindlist(lapply(splitted_list, data.frame), fill=TRUE) 
#    Color  HP  Type
# 1:  Blue 405 Truck
# 2:    NA 400   Car
# 3: White 500 Truck
```

Hope it addresses your problem.

When applied to your test data from Dropbox with split condition `cumsum(d==1)`, it resulted in

```
structure(list(Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("New", "Used"
), class = "factor"), Make = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Peterbilt", 
"Kenworth", "Volvo", "International"), class = "factor"), Model = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("367 Tri-Drive c/w 58'' Sleeper", 
"T800 T/A Tractor", "T800 Tandem Tractor w/ 38'' Sleeper", "W900 Tri-Drive Sleeper Truck Tractor", 
"367 T/A Wet-Kit Tractor c/w 58'' Sleeper", "VNL64T 780-730", 
"367 T/A Wet Kit Tractor c/w       58'' Sleeper", "ProStar +122"
), class = "factor"), Kilometres = structure(1:16, .Label = c("3,360 km", 
"82,230 km", "98,521 km", "170,422 km", "3,367 km", "3,421 km", 
"2,157 km", "3,444 km", "3,427 km", "3,982 km", "23,293 km", 
"27,215 km", "72,000 km", "60,657 km", "36,236 km", "33,000 km"
), class = "factor"), Stock.Number = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 13L, 14L, 15L), .Label = c("12949", 
"10720", "10722", "13227", "12180", "12179", "12181", "12954", 
"12955", "12182", "12953", "12509", "10838", "463555", "463543"
), class = "factor"), Engine = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Cummins ISX15  (550 hp)", 
"Cummins ISX15 (550hp)", "Cummins ISX15  (600 hp)", "Cummins ISX15  (550hp)", 
"Cummins ISX"), class = "factor"), Number.of.Hours = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, NA, 13L, NA, NA
), .Label = c("44", "2,712", "2,790", "4,925", "38", "46", "64", 
"45", "43", "78", "394", "458", "1,822"), class = "factor"), 
    Front.axle = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000lb)", 
    "Dana Spicer D2000  (20,000 lb)", "Meritor FL941      (20,000 lb)", 
    "Dana Spicer E14621  (14,600 lb", "Arvin Meritor 13200 lb"
    ), class = "factor"), Rear.axle = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Dana T69-170    (wide track) t", 
    "Dana D46-170HPW (46,000 lb) ta", "Meritor RZ-166    (69,000 lb)", 
    "Dana D46-170     (46,000lb) ta", "Dana D46-170HP (46,000lb) tand", 
    "Arvin Meritor 40000 lb", "Arvin Meritor 46000 lb"), class = "factor"), 
    Suspension = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Peterbilt Air-Trak  (66,000lb)", 
    "Neway ADZ252    (52,000lb) Air", "Kenworth AG690 (69,000lb) Air", 
    "Peterbilt Air-Trak  (46,000lb)", "Int'l IROS"), class = "factor"), 
    Wheelbase = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("267''", "244''", 
    "259''", "228 in", "236 in"), class = "factor"), Transmission = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 4L, 4L
    ), .Label = c("RTLO18918B  Fuller (18 speed)", "Fuller 18 spd main AT1202 2 sp", 
    "18 speed main &     4 speed au", "Eaton Fuller D/O (18 spd)"
    ), class = "factor"), Price = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("$217,770", 
    "$199,500", "$197,750", "$193,300", "$189,880", "$186,600", 
    "$185,000", "$171,800", "$168,750", "$165,900"), class = "factor"), 
    Style.Trim = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA), .Label = "VNL64T780-730", class = "factor"), 
    Brakes = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Air", class = "factor"), 
    Mfg.Exterior.Colour = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), .Label = "White", class = "factor"), 
    Tires = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("11R22.5", "11R/22.5"
    ), class = "factor"), Engine..HP. = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("450", 
    "475"), class = "factor"), Exterior.Colour = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "White", class = "factor")), .Names = c("Status", 
"Make", "Model", "Kilometres", "Stock.Number", "Engine", "Number.of.Hours", 
"Front.axle", "Rear.axle", "Suspension", "Wheelbase", "Transmission", 
"Price", "Style.Trim", "Brakes", "Mfg.Exterior.Colour", "Tires", 
"Engine..HP.", "Exterior.Colour"), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Nice use of data.table! +1 Unfortunately, as @AlexT indicated in the comments, his real data is not regular, and does not satisfy the ascending-order assumption. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly not the best solution, as it uses a while loop. However, using `tidyr`, or your other favourite reshaping package.

```
testlist <- c("Blue", "405", "Truck", "400", "Car", "White", "500", "Truck")
testnames <- c("Color", "HP", "Type", "HP", "Type", "Color", "HP", "Type")

df <- data.frame(names = testnames, attributes = testlist, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



# need to count number of vehicles inside data frame

# initialise while loop counters
df_index = 1
vehicle_index = vector(mode = "integer", length = nrow(df))
vehicle_count = 1

# now loop through the data frame to find attributes 
# which belong to vehicle 1, 2, 3, etc...
while(df_index <= nrow(df)){
    if (sum(c("Color", "HP", "Type") == df$names[df_index:(df_index+2)]) == 3) {
        vehicle_index[df_index:(df_index+2)] <- vehicle_count
        df_index = df_index + 3
        vehicle_count = vehicle_count + 1
    } else if (sum(c("Color", "HP", "Type") %in% df$names[df_index:(df_index+1)]) == 2) {
        vehicle_index[df_index:(df_index+1)] <- vehicle_count
        df_index = df_index + 2
        vehicle_count = vehicle_count + 1
    } else {
        vehicle_index[df_index:(df_index)] <- vehicle_count
        df_index = df_index + 1
        vehicle_count = vehicle_count + 1
    }

}

# finally, label the vehicle attributes with the vehicle number,
# and spread the data.
df_final <- data.frame(df, vehicle_index = vehicle_index)

tidyr::spread(df_final, key = "names", value = "attributes")
```